# Custom Computer Randomly Restarting and not Booting

Tags: boot, shutdown

Recently, I built a gaming computer (specs below).  For the first month or so, everything worked fine.  Recently, it began having a problem where it would randomly shutdown and restart a few seconds after powering down.  This occurred at times when the core temp wasn't particularly high (highest was 70 C), and even occurred once during a test when there were no active programs.

A few days ago, I had to travel, so I disconnected the surge protector from the wall.  I just got back today, plugged in the surge protector, and pressed the power button on my computer.  Nothing.  I waited a few minutes, and tried again... nothing.  I flipped the switch on the PSU, waited a few seconds, then flipped it again.  The power light on my USB hub comes on, but the computer won't boot.

> Any suggestions on how to get it to boot again, and maybe why it was randomly restarting?

## Specs

PSU: [EVGA 450 B1, 80+ BRONZE 450W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01F5LX55K)

RAM: 2x [Crucial 8GB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MMLUZ2I)

SSD: [Crucial MX300 275GB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IAGSD5O)

GPU: [EVGA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KUADE3O)

MoBo: [ASRock Motherboard Motherboards B250M PRO4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N0LMLMM)

GPU: [Intel Pentium G Series 3.50 GHz Dual-Core LGA 1151 Processor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NCE8T92)

Case: [Fractal Design Core 1000 USB 3.0 Case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CUSUV0O)

## Updates

4:33) Jumped the power and ground pins on the motherboard to discharge them.  Computer now turns on, but there is no output from the HDMI cable to the screen.  There is a little red LED lit up next to the blue "on" LED on the case.  After pressing the power button to do a hard reset, the computer takes another ~30 seconds before it shuts down.  Turn computer back on, still no image on the screen, but there's a little audio pop when the screen comes on.

6:06) After reassembly, HDMI cable was plugged into motherboard output, not GPU output.  Fixed, and now image is back.  However, random shut down problem still not resolved.

Comment: Sounds like a PSU issue

Comment: What's a good way to test if it's a PSU issue?  I've double checked all the connections, and they're secure.  If it comes to it, I can send it back, because I thought ahead and got a warranty.

Comment: Your PC isn’t turning on and it was randomly restarting previously.

Comment: Okay, cheers.  I'm gonna send off for a replacement.

Comment: With all due respect to @Ramhound, there is nothing here to suggest this is a power supply issue any more than it suggests it is a motherboard, memory, or CPU issue or possibly any other device plugged in to the motherboard. You should start by unplugging/removing all unnecessary items from the motherboard and see if you can simply get it to POST. Remove one or both memory modules and see if you can get it to beep or do anything else different. Try reseating the CPU. There are a lot of other steps you can take before guessing and waiting for a power supply.